# Building objects in javascript, without "if(!a[k]) a[k] = []"

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, mapreduce

When building objects using reduce, I often have crappy code like this:

```
function mapArticlesByTagAndId(articles) {
    return articles.reduce((collector = {}, article) => {
        const { tag, id } = article;
        if(!collector[tag]) collector[tag] = {};

        collector[tag][id] = article;
        return collector;
    })
}
```

I would love to one line this, but I can't figure out a way to do it.
If only assigning a property to undefined created an object =P [Obviously this would cause different problems haha]

Comment: could you please post the complete code? this one is missing the second parameter of the `reduce()`.

Comment: More specifically "code like this" is not good enough for Code Review. Please post real code that accomplishes a stated task, as per the requirements in the [help/on-topic] and [ask].

Comment: 200, this is real code. The context could be literally anything and it wouldn't change how one would structure this code. I could rename myArr to articles, then as far as anyone knows it's real code.

The only difference in context would be performance, which I'm not picky about.

Comment: As @IgorSoloydenko says, at least provide a full function call.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one variant which gets rid of the explicit `if` at the cost of potential useless reassignment. This, however, does not take away the necessity of ensuring that the `k` key has a collection object in place...

```
const result =
  myArr.reduce((collector, { k, j, v }) => {
    collector[k] = collector[k] || [];
    collector[k][j] = v;
    return collector;
  }, {});
```

Assuming, **ES6** syntax is fine with you, here's another variant. Please notice that it the spread operator (`...` will result in copying the `...collector[k]` item-by-item). I.e. this is less performant and may be an issue for large objects.

```
const result =
  myArr.reduce((collector, { k, j, v }) => {
   collector[k] = collector[k] ? [...collector[k], v] : [ v ];
   return collector;
  }, {});
```

which may be compacted further:

```
const result =
  myArr.reduce((collector, { k, j, v }) =>
    (collector[k] = collector[k] ? [...collector[k], v] : [ v ], collector),
    {});
```

### Update 1

```
const result =
  myArr.reduce((collector, { k, j, v }) =>
    (collector[k] = !collector[k] ? [v] : (collector[k].push(v), collector[k])),
    {});
```

Comment: Thanks for all the options! These are options I already knew of, although truth be told I think was intrinsically avoiding the third one, because of all the newly created objects, even though it would technically create a one line reduce function, which is what I was ideally looking for.

If there was a clean way to do the last option, without create a new object during each iteration, that would be ideal, however I worry that may not be possible.

Comment: @user1272 I'll take a look into it more, at the moment still unsure whether I'll be able to improve it our not.

Comment: @JasonMcCarrell what do you think about the updated version? I reversed the condition to be `!collector[k]` for readability. `(collector[k].push(v), collector[k])` will push a new value into the array and return the array itself, the JS's comma operator is handy here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator We can not omit the `,collector[k]` part because the previous expression (`.push()`) returns the length of the array after the insertion, rather than the array itself